# edit2Textbox won`t go away

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-edittext

I have a weird problem.
I have a test.xml file, it included 2 edittext boxes (edit1 and edit2).
I removed the edit2text box completly from the test.xml but it keeps apparing when i run my program?

I already deleted the app from the phone and restarted eclipse and phone but nothing seems to help.
It keeps coming back.

FY: I`m running eclipse without a emulator, i don`t know if this has something to do with it.

Does somebody know how the edit2 goes away?

My code, which calls the test.xml

```
@Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
        // create the grid item mapping 
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn); 

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1"}; 
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1 }; <<< should only be 1 edittext

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

        HashMap<String, String> map; 

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn); 
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("td"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) { 
            map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text());  
            fillMaps.add(map); 

            System.out.println("Hashmap: " + map); 

        }  

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.test, from, to);  
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit: Solved by removing this code in the edit1text box in test.xml, i don`t know what this has to do with the edit2 box but ok, it did the trick:

```
android:editable="false"
android:enabled="true"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project

Comment: I solved it!
See edited code.

Comment: Hi dten, i`m not sure if i cleaned the project but now it runs ok :)

Comment: you added something to the XML which would cause it to rebuild. Cleaning would have one the same. Those lines you added wouldn't normally change it from not working to working unless it had missed a build :-)

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project :-)  you seem to have old XML files